# Accessing Remote_User

Tags: c#, httprequest, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I am trying to find a way to obtain my Remote_User so I can login my user using machine credentials to a web application (Intranet application). I am unable to figure out how to get this information as when I look into my keys in my MS_HttpContext, it doesn't appear to be set. This is the code I have tried.

Inside my WebApiConfiguration I have the following

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

  HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() {
    UseDefaultCredentials =true
  };
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

  builder.EntitySet<Model.User.User>("User"); 

  config.MapODataServiceRoute("Application", "api", builder.GetEdmModel()); 
  // added so api controllers can return json encoded data. 
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")); 

}
```

and inside my controller which I try and access this header, I am unable to, I have looped through the request and printed out all keys and values, and it doesn't appear to be set.

```
  var p = Request.Properties; 

  var t = ((HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.ServerVariables;

  foreach (var s in t) {
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", s, t.Get(s.ToString()).ToString());
  }
```

I have looked around to try and find a solution, and all I was able to find was the above solution and variations of it, all of which I have tried to no success. Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated. The only guesses I have is to why this occurs is due to the use of IIS Express instead of full IIS.

Comment: You need to use IIS with integrated authentication enabled for this to work, IIRC.

Comment: Once I moved over to native IIS instead of IIS express, I was able to get this working. Thank you